# Is EFLAGS a general purpose register?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers, eflags

Some tutorials say that the `EFLAGS` register is a general purpose register, while other tutorials say that it is not a general purpose register.

So which one is it?!

Comment: It is not a general purpose register. It is effectively a status register.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register

Answer (score 6):

No,

[It is not because](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register):

- You cannot directly address it; there is no `MOV EFLAGS, Value` instruction.
- You cannot perform calculations using `EFLAGS`.
- You cannot specify `EFLAGS` as an explicit source or destination in any instruction.

In fact, there are only 4 instructions that allow you to address the `eflags` register as a whole: [`PUSHF`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PUSHF:PUSHFD.html), [`POPF`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/POPF:POPFD:POPFQ.html), [`SAHF`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SAHF.html), and [`LAHF`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/LAHF.html)
And even these instructions only act upon a limited set of bits within the register.

In fact `eflags` is as far away from a general purpose register as you can get. It's a special purpose status register.

Answer (score 4):

They are not General Purpose Registers. But rather, "Program Status and Control Register" as for [Intel's Documentation](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-1-manual.html), Volume A (section 3.4.1, page 73): [image]

Comment: I would even say that `ESP` is not a "general purpose register" because it **must** point to the stack.

Comment: @MartinRosenau, No it does not, RSP can point to anything. An application can choose to forgo the use of a stack. If it does you can use RSP for any purpose you like.

Comment: @Johan The word "general purpose" means that something can be used for any purpose. In fact when CPL=3 the ESP register may have any value - but only as long as you don't use the `call` or `push` instructions! However when CPL=0 ESP must definitely point to the stack: An invalid value in the ESP register (e.g. pointing to a non-mapped address) would definitely cause a CPU reset because of a "triple fault" if any interrupt occurs! (For example an NMI.) This is why I say that ESP is not a "general purpose" register.

Comment: @Martin Rosenau: `esp` can be encoded as a source or destination in most places a GPR can be encoded so I'd consider it a GPR for this reason. (`esp` cannot be encoded as the index of a 32-bit SIB addressing mode however.)

Comment: @ecm "GPR" means that a register can be used for anything. If `esp` is a "GPR", it is possible to define a calling convention where the first three integer arguments are passed in registers `ecx`, `esi` and `esp`. The C code `myFunction(1,2,3);` would result in the following assembler code: `mov ecx,1`, `mov esi,2`, `mov esp,3` ... and what's the next instruction? By the way: As long as there is no instruction `lodsd ebx, esi`, even `eax` is not a real "GPR" because there are instructions that implicitly use the `eax` register!

Comment: @ecm As I have written in an answer on [Retrocomputing Stackexchange](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5121/why-are-first-four-x86-gprs-named-in-such-unintuitive-order#10985), all registers of x86-16 had some "intended purpose" and therefore x86-16 did not have any "GPR" at all. In contrast to this, registers R0-R13 of an ARM-1 or ARM-2 CPU or R1-R30 of MIPS can be used for anything.

Comment: @Martin Rosenau: You're correct, but I specifically listed the encodings that allow to use `esp` as a source or destination, and that I would consider it a GPR *for this reason*. Your example, however, can be made to work with `esp` as a parameter if you use any other GPR as an improvised stack pointer, eg `mov dword [ebx - 4], my_return_address` \ `sub ebx, 4` \ `jmp my_function` \ `my_return_address:` then to return you do `add ebx, 4` \ `jmp near dword [ebx - 4]` =)

Comment: Re: whether ESP / RSP is a GPR: [Why are rbp and rsp called general purpose registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51347294).  I agree with @ecm on this; it can be an operand for `add` so it's a GPR.  Also, Intel lists it as a GPR in their manual here and in [How to know if a register is a "general purpose register"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45538021) .  Re: Martin's "what's the next instruction" in a hypothetical calling convention?  `mov [ret_addr], imm32` or `mov eax, imm32`, then `jmp myFunction`.  Or use a different reg as a user-space stack pointer and push a return address.

Comment: Of course if you invent narrower definitions of GPR, you can exclude everything except maybe some of R8-R15.  Some of those definitions are even useful distinctions, like ESP/RSP but unlike anything else.  But the fact that it's extremely inconvenient and somewhat inefficient to operate the machine with ESP not being a stack pointer doesn't mean it's not a GPR in the standard sense of having a register-number.