# Any ideas what is causing this weird performance drop seemingly depending on the choice of registers?

Tags: assembly, optimization, x86, x86-64

I've been trying to optimize this unrolled loop a bit further:

```
some_loop:
UNROLL_CNT = 256                  ; best for Core i9-9900k at least
UNROLL_I = 0
repeat UNROLL_CNT
    ;
    ; Block 1
    ;
    movzx r9, byte ptr[r10]       ; tmp = s[i]
    add r11b, r9b                 ; j += s[i]
    movzx rax, byte ptr[r11]      ; s[i] = s[j]
    mov byte ptr[r10], al         ;
    mov byte ptr[r11], r9b        ; s[j] = tmp

    add r9b, al                   ; tmp = s[i] + s[j]
    inc r10b                      ; i++
    movzx rax, byte ptr[rsp + r9] ; rax = s[tmp]
    xor byte ptr [rcx+UNROLL_I], al ; *data ^= rax => *data ^= s[s[i] + s[j]]
UNROLL_I = UNROLL_I + 1
endm
```

..and I thought I'd try to interleave 2 iterations together (with an extra set of registers), but before I even got there, to my surprise, the performance dropped to half just by using the new set of registers(?):

```
some_loop:
UNROLL_CNT = 256
UNROLL_I = 0
repeat UNROLL_CNT/2
    ;
    ; Block 1
    ;
    movzx r9, byte ptr[r10]       ; tmp = s[i]
    add r11b, r9b                 ; j += s[i]
    movzx rax, byte ptr[r11]      ; s[i] = s[j]
    mov byte ptr[r10], al         ;
    mov byte ptr[r11], r9b        ; s[j] = tmp

    add r9b, al                   ; tmp = s[i] + s[j]
    add r10b, 2                   ; i+=2 (for next iter.)
    movzx rax, byte ptr[rsp + r9] ; al= s[tmp]
    xor byte ptr [rcx+UNROLL_I], al ; *data ^= s[s[i] + s[j]]
UNROLL_I = UNROLL_I + 1

    ;
    ; Block 2
    ;  same as above with r9->r12, r10->r13, r11->r14, rax->r15
    ;
    movzx r12, byte ptr[r13]      ; tmp = s[i]
    add r14b, r12b                ; j += s[i]
    movzx r15, byte ptr[r14]      ; s[i] = s[j]
    mov byte ptr[r13], r15b       ;
    mov byte ptr[r14], r12b       ; s[j] = tmp

    add r12b, r15b                ; tmp = s[i] + s[j]
    add r13b, 2                   ; i+=2 (for next iter.)
    movzx r15, byte ptr[rsp + r12] ; r15b = s[tmp]
    xor byte ptr [rcx+UNROLL_I], r15b ; *data ^= s[s[i] + s[j]]
UNROLL_I = UNROLL_I + 1
endm
```

So the first listing repeats 256 times x Block 1, and the second listing repeats 128 times x (Block 1, Block 2). As you can see, the instructions are virtually identical except for the registers used and the `inc r10b` instruction which turned into `add r10b, 2`. That, I would expect, would make listing 1 equivalent to listing 2 performance-wise.

I'm looking for any references on specific GP registers being faster than others on x86-64 but there don't seem to be any, which makes me think this is not a register-issue, but rather some caching / parallelization issue (though the instructions on each block are quite tightly dependant on each other; not sure how it would perform parallelization on that).

Do you have any ideas what might be causing that extreme performance drop when bringing Block 2 in the picture?

If you have any other insights on how to further optimize Block 1 itself that would be also more than welcome, as that is my end goal, not the interleaving thingy (which I don't even know for sure it would improve overall performance).

Things I've tried on the second listing:

- Reducing the `UNROLL_CNT`: the performance improves down to `UNROLL_CNT = 32`, at which point it is still around 1.5x slower than the single block listing.
- Replacing the `add r10b/r13b, 2` with `inc r10b/r13b`: as expected, it doesn't make much of a difference.
- Replacing the second block with a block identical to the first one (same registers): and, as expected, the performance comes back up (did that just for sanity)
- Edit: Also tried replacing the registers in the single-block version with r12, r13, r14, r15: performance is fast, so this definitely isn’t a register issue.

Btw, in case you're wondering if the issue is with the loop condition, here it is:

```
    add rcx, UNROLL_CNT           ; data += UNROLL_CNT
    dec rbx                       ; if --num_unrolled_loops
    jnz some_loop                 ;   continue
```

As you can see it's on rbx, which is not used at all on the unrolled loop body.

Comment: are you sure you are using the correct register size? the best is a 32bit reg, but if possible use an 8bit reg as its faster

Comment: I believe so, as I've put quite some thought to this. For the most part, the algorithm (RC4) forces me to use 8-bit registers (it's all byte-wise operations). For the `movzx reg64, rm` parts, I've tried using 8-bit dst registers but that is significantly slower (I believe due to partial register stalls). But if you have something specific in mind, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Using different registers can have different consequences for the instruction encoding, such as needing a REX prefix or not, but that usually matters very little and I don't think it would explain this.

Comment: Correctness first: adding to the low 8 bits of a pointer looks questionable.  Unless the base of your array is aligned to a 256-byte boundary, there may be a carry out of the low 8 bits, which you will lose, and thus get the wrong answer.

Comment: It seems to me that a more natural way to write it would be to do your math on indices instead of raw pointers, and use `[base+idx]` addressing modes to access your array.  Also, since you are already zero-extending, you can avoid the partial register issues by doing your arithmetic on the 32-bit registers, and if you need a "mod 256" result, apply a final `movzx` before using it as an index.

Comment: The usual advice with registers is for code size, which is indirectly related to speed due to icache usage, especially here where every extra byte gets multiplied by 256 when you unroll.  You want to prefer registers that don't require REX prefixes.  So that means preferring the "original eight" registers RAX-RSP and avoiding R8-R15; preferring AL-DL as your 8-bit registers and avoiding DIL,SIL, BPL as well as AH-DH; and using the 32- instead of 64-bit versions for data wherever possible.

Comment: Keep in mind that writes to 32-bit registers automatically zero-extend to 64-bits.  So for instance, `movzx rax, byte ptr [x]` can be replaced by `movzx eax, byte ptr [x]` which is equivalent, and one byte shorter if the effective address doesn't use R8-R15 (if it does then you would need a REX anyway).

Comment: @NateEldredge awesome advice, thanks, will try all that and see if it helps. Correctness is there and verified, adding to the low 8 bits is intentional and rsp (the buffer) is indeed aligned to a 256-byte boundary (omitted the initialisation to focus on the loop). Doing the math on indices was indeed my initial implementation and then I managed to squeeze some performance by doing it directly on the pointers which also required the 256-byte alignment you pointed out. So that is intentional too. The rest looks promising, I will try asap and report back. Thank you.

Comment: What CPU?  Perhaps `[r13]` and `[r12]` causing larger code-size than `[r10]` (see *[Why are RBP and RSP called general-purpose registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36529449)*) is stopping it from fitting in the uop cache, or is making something worse for uop-cache related reasons.  On Intel, check performance counters for `idq.mite_uops` (legacy decode); you want it to be a small fraction of `uops_issued.any` (total fused-domain uops from the front-end) for a loop.

Comment: Updates: @NateEldredge by replacing all R8-15 to RAX-RSP and using only AL-DL for 8-bit registers as well as using `movxz e*x, [...]` instead of `movzx r*x, [...]`, the single-block loop improved by ~0.5%.

@PeterCordes the CPU is a Core i9-9900k. Will need to check on how to get those counters as they're new to me. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

try this code, I haven't tested it, but if you break it up into 4 parts per loop since 256 is divisible by 4, this should be faster.

```
some_loop:
    UNROLL_CNT = 256
    UNROLL_I = 0

    repeat UNROLL_CNT/4   ; Unroll the loop further
    ;
    ; Block 1
    ;
        movzx r8, byte ptr [r10]       ; tmp = s[i]
        add r11b, r8b                  ; j += s[i]
        movzx rax, byte ptr [r11]      ; s[i] = s[j]
        mov byte ptr [r10], al         ;
        mov byte ptr [r11], r8b        ; s[j] = tmp

        add r8b, al                    ; tmp = s[i] + s[j]
        inc r10b                       ; i++
        movzx rax, byte ptr [rsp + r8] ; rax = s[tmp]
        xor byte ptr [rcx + UNROLL_I], al ; *data ^= rax => *data ^= s[s[i] + s[j]]

        ; Repeat the block for the next set of unrolled instructions
        movzx r8, byte ptr [r10]       
        add r11b, r8b                  
        movzx rax, byte ptr [r11]      
        mov byte ptr [r10], al         
        mov byte ptr [r11], r8b        

        add r8b, al                    
        inc r10b                       
        movzx rax, byte ptr [rsp + r8] 
        xor byte ptr [rcx + UNROLL_I + 1], al ;

        ; Repeat the block for the next set of unrolled instructions
        movzx r8, byte ptr [r10]       
        add r11b, r8b                  
        movzx rax, byte ptr [r11]      
        mov byte ptr [r10], al         
        mov byte ptr [r11], r8b        

        add r8b, al                    
        inc r10b                       
        movzx rax, byte ptr [rsp + r8] 
        xor byte ptr [rcx + UNROLL_I + 2], al ;

        ; Repeat the block for the next set of unrolled instructions
        movzx r8, byte ptr [r10]       
        add r11b, r8b                  
        movzx rax, byte ptr [r11]      
        mov byte ptr [r10], al         
        mov byte ptr [r11], r8b        

        add r8b, al                    
        inc r10b                       
        movzx rax, byte ptr [rsp + r8] 
        xor byte ptr [rcx + UNROLL_I + 3], al ;

        ; Update UNROLL_I for the next iteration
        UNROLL_I = UNROLL_I + 4
```

Purpose of my code

1. Use General-Purpose registers instead of using specific registers like r9 and r11, use general-purpose registers (rax, rbx, rcx, etc.) to give the compiler more freedom in register allocation.
2. Memory access optimization minimize memory accesses. If possible, load values into registers and perform multiple operations before storing back to memory.

Comment: This is bit-by-bit identical to my first listing as that is what the `repeat` macro does in the first place (repeats block of code for you to not have to copy them over and over again). Performance is also good, as expected, but I'm back to square one.