# cmp with any value equals 0

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

I am trying to create a switch statement in assembly; however, I seem to always get stuck on the first case, no matter what the value is:

```
SECTION .data
    newLine    db  0xA,0xD
    NewLen     equ $- newLine

    nvalue     dw  2          ; nth number for case

    msg0       db  'a', 0xa 
    msg1       db  'b', 0xa 
    msg2       db  'c', 0xa  
    msg3       db  'd', 0xa 
    defaultMsg db  'e'

SECTION .text
    global  _start

    _start:
        mov eax, nvalue

        cmp eax, 0
        je  case0
        cmp eax, 1
        je  case1
        cmp eax, 2
        je  case2
        cmp eax, 3
        je  case3

        case0:
            mov  edx, 2
            mov  eax, 4
            mov  ebx, 1
            mov  ecx, msg0        
            mov  edx, 1        
            int  80h
            call printNL
            call quit
        case1:
            mov  edx, 2
            mov  eax, 4
            mov  ebx, 1
            mov  ecx, msg1        
            mov  edx, 1        
            int  80h
            call printNL
            call quit
        case2:
            mov  edx, 2
            mov  eax, 4
            mov  ebx, 1
            mov  ecx, msg2        
            mov  edx, 1        
            int  80h
            call printNL
            call quit
        case3: 
           mov  edx, 2
           mov  eax, 4
           mov  ebx, 1
           mov  ecx, msg3        
           mov  edx, 1        
           int  80h
           call printNL
           call quit

        mov  edx, 2
        mov  eax, 4
        mov  ebx, 1
        mov  ecx, defaultMsg        
        mov  edx, 1        
        int  80h
        call printNL
        call quit

    printNL:
        mov edx, NewLen
        mov ecx, newLine
        mov ebx, 1       
        mov eax, 4      
        int 80h

    quit:
        mov ebx, 0
        mov eax, 1
        int 80h
        ret
```

The string output is always 'a' (case0 for when the nvalue variable is 0). Why is it doing this when nvalue is 2?

Comment: You want `mov eax, [nvalue]` See [section 2.2.2 NASM Requires Square Brackets For Memory References in the nasm manual](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.2.2) You were loading the address not the value. Also you used the wrong directive, you want `dd` for a double word. Alternatively use `movzx eax, word [nvalue]`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jester ! That helps me understand it better.

Comment: `call quit` is very confusing! Better write `jmp quit`.

Comment: The block where you print *defaultMsg* should go directly above the label `case0:`. In assembly programming, indenting the text is important for readability, but it doesn't say anything about logical structures like switches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        mov eax, nvalue

        cmp eax, 0
        je  case0
        cmp eax, 1
        je  case1
        cmp eax, 2
        je  case2
        cmp eax, 3
        je  case3

        case0:
```

What this code does is

1. Load the address of `nvalue` into `eax`.
2. Compare this address with 0, 1, 2 and 3.
3. If the comparison with 1, 2 or 3 succeeds, jump away to corresponding labels.
4. Otherwise, jump or fall through to `case0`.

What you actually want, first of all, is to read the *value* of `nvalue` into `eax`. And this is done by

```
mov eax, [nvalue]
```

if you had `nvalue` defined with `dd`. If you leave it as it's now, with `dw`, then the loading could be like

```
movzx eax, word [nvalue]
```

And the second point, you may want to add a jump away before the `case0` label, if you don't want to fall through to it when all comparisons fail.
Alternatively place the block where you print the *defaultMsg*, between `je case3` ... `case0:`. This way you shave off the extra `jmp`.

Comment: Thanks @Ruslan . What do you mean by "jump away"? Are you referring to the 'default' case? If so, I thought my default was where I was printing defaultMsg outside of all my 'case' functions.

Comment: @SJCypher your default is when `je  case3` branch is not taken (`ZF==0`). If it's not taken, you end up executing the `case0` code.

Comment: (off topic: your answer on [Unable to set the lowest byte in a register x86-64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64115162) looks right; what was wrong with it that made you decide to delete it?  You can reply to my comment on that question, instead of this comment thread)

Comment: @PeterCordes I've found that it's not quite right to say that `*L` is something strange: first, yasm and fasm, for example, appear to understand `spl` but not `spb`. And if I do remove this part, what remains will just talk about convenience variables, which seems rather obvious from the comments. In any case that answer needs rework before undeleting.

Comment: See my comments under that question with links for more history of `l` (AMD) vs. `b` (Intel) suffixes for r8..r15.  The original-8 registers always use `l`, for consistency with `al`/`bl`/...  But yes it's especially inconsistent and conflicting with AT&T syntax's convention of `l` = long 32-bit operand-size for mnemonics.

Answer (score -3):

```
replace:
    nvalue     dw  2          ; nth number for case
with:
    nvalue     dd  2          ; nth number for case
```

dos asm is quirky.

Also, you might want to add a default case -- that is why it is falling through.

Comment: Thank you. I thought my default case was the code block printing the "defaultMsg" outside of the 'case' functions. Is that not the case?

Comment: It's not DOS, it's Linux, judging by `int 0x80`.

Comment: 'dos asm' the assembler from dos.

Comment: `nasm` isn't "the assembler from DOS".  It was originally developed as a portable assembler that would run well on non-DOS machines, to make it easy to develop bootloaders like syslinux and isolinux on GNU/Linux machines.  https://nasm.us/

Comment: It uses that ambiguous dos format, which makes it an assembler from dos; worse, it redefines it so that it enters yet a third syntax.   The OP used a `mov symbol, eax`, which a dos assembler would make a load from memory, nasm would turn into what a dos asm would call `lea`; only as would correctly say "syntax error".  So, right, not technically dos, but still dos.