# error: impossible combination of address sizes

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64

I am trying to learn how to shuffle a deck using assembly language. I am fluent in java and I can easily translate java into C but I'm having a hard time with ASM. this is the block of code I have issues with right now:

```
MOV R8, [RDI+RSI*4]

MOV R9, [RDI+RDX*4]

MOV  [RDI+RSI*4], R9

MOV  [RDI+RDX*4], R8
```

I keep getting

```
error: impossible combination of address sizes
```

It was run with the command

```
nasm -f elf FILE-NAME.asm
```

I'm guessing it has issues with the registers I am using but I have no idea about the rules in assembly. I am learning using [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming) but if anyone has any recommendations about other places I could learn better about it, that would be helpful. I also saw on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1753627/4968642) that all the registers used have the same size, so why the error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're writing 64bit code, but your `-f elf` will put NASM in 32bit mode. Use `elf64` instead:

```
$ cat foo.asm
MOV R8, [RDI+RSI*4]

$ nasm -f elf foo.asm
foo.asm:1: error: impossible combination of address sizes

$ nasm -f elf64 foo.asm
(no output)
```

Comment: Or better, `nasm -f elf64`.

Comment: @Jester Not just “or better.”  Actually, `BITS 64` does not solve the problem.

Comment: Note that the use of `-f elf` or even that `nasm` was involved at all was not mentioned in the original question.