# What is this "r8d" in x64dbg?

Tags: reverse-engineering, x64dbg

I'm debugging my x64 c++ program to learn how it look in x64dbg.  I see some register for r8-r15 on the right window, but I don't see `r8d`.  There were others like `r15d` too.  So what is it?

Here is a screenshot of my x64dbg.
[image: Here is a screenshot of my x64dbg.]

Comment: Note that `xor r8d, r8d` actually has the effect of zeroing the entire 64-bit `r8` register, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6, just like `xor r8, r8` would.  For the "low" general-purpose registers rax-rdx, rsi, rdi, rsp, rbp this trick yields a savings in code space: `xor edx, edx` does the same thing as `xor rdx, rdx` but the former is one byte shorter due to not needing a REX prefix.  For the "high" registers r8-r15, it actually makes no difference because the REX prefix is needed in both cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `d` suffix means its (the 64-bit register's) lower double-word. For example, `r8d` is accessing `r8`'s lower 32-bit as if it is a 32-bit register.

You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1753618/3501958).